# Should I have a password in my application

Tags: .net, passwords, theory

I'm wondering if I need a password in my app. I'm targetting home users where multiple people can use the same application, but each has their own profile. The data is not sensitive, but could be embarrassing (health, weight, etc). Is this enough to warrant a password or is the profile enough?

**Edit** To clarify some more about my application. I will store the users' weight, height and eating habits/values (calories, nutrients, etc.) The user is free to name the profile whatever they want and is not asked for any true personally identifiable information. The data will be stored on their local computer. The reason I wanted to add the password was in case Wifey did not want Hubby to see her weight or vice versa.

Comment: The data, if personally identifiable is sensitive and is, at the very least, subject to [HIPAA](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/index.html) guidelines.

Comment: What country is the app going to be used? Where is the data from? Where is the data stored? "Personal information" is covered by legislation in different countries.

Comment: @sumo, depends on the country. e.g. A UK app used by Brits stored in the UK comes under the DPA: http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/data_protection.aspx

Comment: @StuperUser, I will provide a link from a webpage so it could be used everywhere, but I won't be asking for specific identifiable information. The user is free to call the profile whatever they wish. The only health information that will be stored will be the users' weight, height, and meals (calories, nutrients, etc).

Comment: Is this a web app or a something people will download and install?

Comment: @Gabe - it's a WPF app that can be downloaded and installed.

Comment: @Sumo: HIPAA does not apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most definitely should implement protection for people's data.  Also look at local laws that protect data.  In the United States all health information are protected by HIPAA regulations which will require SSL connection to the site - there are many other rules.

Some people might not want others to see their information, so you should also consider settings to allow them to keep their data private.

Comment: I suggest following Wii Fit's example by making the password *optional*.

Comment: HIPAA only applies to "covered entities" -- in general, health care providers, health care clearinghouses, or health plans. See http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/coveredentities/index.html for more details. Odds are the OP is *not* covered. That doesn't mean he shouldn't provide appropriate protections, it just means that he's not legally required to.

Comment: Not legally required to in the US. I'm from Canada... if I sell across borders do I still have to comply? I would think yes, but what if I don't? I'm not saying I won't, just curious.

Comment: @John - My experience is based on the fact that I am building an application in the US for a company that require that their data be protected.  You may not have to (from what Gabe said), but it might be wise to research the cross-border legal aspects further (just in case). It does appear from your edit that the personal identifyable information is limited.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely should put a password in. Nobody will spite you for added security within reason. By-user data, whether you consider it sensitive or not, should be password protected.

Comment: It should be up to the user whether to password-protect their own data. Would you fault Excel if you had to enter a password every time you wanted to access a spreadsheet? I would.

Comment: Excel is software used to generate spreadsheets, personal or not. You can't group Excel with the op's software.

Comment: For comparison sake can you think of another app that stores information such as this but does/doesn't have password protection?